# Imageview down the performance of my app

Tags: android, performance, imageview

I am working on an Android app where, once a user clicks a login button, the app launches an AsyncTask to verify account details with a remote server. That part works fine by itself and doesn't make my app slow. However, when you click the login button, it launches a second activity where I have 4 ImageViews. When I added that part of the app, it became significantly slower (from less than a second to about 5 seconds loading time). I load the images into the ImageView from the XML layout file directly, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My question is that do ImageViews make your app slow, and if so, how do you optimize their performance?

Comment: what is the Image size in terms on resolution and dimensions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working my own app when I actually experienced this too. The reason is because if the files are to big they take a while to load into memory and set as the Image View. There is two ways you could really sort it out.

1: Get a smaller version of the picture. Smaller pictures come up faster and aren't prone to an OutOfMemory exception which kills the app :(.

2: A better way is to use the Picasso api. I used this APIs to add images in list views, expandable list view with pictures in them. The app was fast and fluid :)

Picasso's api would be your best bet ant it is easy to implement.

Edit:
Here is the link to the site to get the APIs :)
[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Thanks! For me, the first solution worked, as my images were 1024x1024 px! I scaled them down to 100x100 and it works beautifully.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)! Hope the rest of the app goes well!

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could figure this out is to create an image in photoshop that has all the buttons laid out where you want them on top of the image.  Interpret it into your app and put regular buttons over top of the imagebutton pictures that you placed onto your background image.  Set the size accordingly to your images of your buttons and then set the background of each button to @null so they aren't seen.  Now trying to figure out how to interpret this into orientation view even though I don't think I'll be using orientationview. OH AND CHANGED THE EXTENSION TO A GIF TO SAVE ON DATA RATHER THEN PNG.

Hope this helps I'm sort of new at coding on android as I have lots of experience with HTML .
Cheers

THANKS FOR THE DOWN LIKE I WAS SORT OF NEW AT THE TIME OF NOT KNOW OTHER WAYS TO SET THIS... THANKS THOUGH, MORONS